# How to join elements of a list that fulfill a specific criteria?

Tags: python, string, list

```
x_list = ["I", "live", "in", "New", "-", "York", "City", ".", "I", "am" "from", "New", "-", "Delhi"]
```

This is my list. What I want is to join the word preceding and after the hyphen "-". So that my list becomes.

```
x_list = ["I", "live", "in", "New-York", "City", ".", "I", "am", "from", "New-Delhi"]
```

Is there a short-elegant way of doing this?

Comment: How is this list created? It'd probably be easier to handle this before the words are split out.

Comment: also don't call your variable `list`

Comment: Unfortunately this was in a dataset and I am expected to clean it. If this was normal text I could have easily used regex to tokenize them properly.

Comment: @timgeb that is just an example.

Comment: @timgeb added an edit with more hyphens. It is a huge dataset with a lot of hyphens.

Comment: Umm... probably a naive approach, but does `' '.join(x_list).replace(' - ', '-').split()` work?

Comment: @JonClements As long as there are no `' - '` inside other words: probably. (you need to `split` again afterwards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can an `enumerate`d `for`-loop:

```
lst = ["I", "live", "in", "New", "-", "York", "City"]
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item == '-':
        lst[index-1:index+2] = [''.join(lst[index-1:index+2])]

print(lst)  # ['I', 'live', 'in', 'New-York', 'City']
```

or if you're dealing with short lists and few `'-'` (like in your example) you could also use a `while` loop. However this has quadratic runtime behaviour so don't use this for large lists with lots of `'-'` if you care about performance:

```
lst = ["I", "live", "in", "New", "-", "York", "City"]
while '-' in lst:
    pos = lst.index('-')
    lst[pos-1:pos+2] = [''.join(lst[pos-1:pos+2])]

print(lst)  # ['I', 'live', 'in', 'New-York', 'City']
```

Comment: The first version is quadratic in number of hyphens.

Comment: @enedil Yes, that's why I also included the second version :) Do you think it needs a more obvious warning in the answer?

Comment: I believe so. Softwere engineers (esp. beginners) aren't cautious about such issues.

Comment: @enedil Thank you. I originally thought the question was about short lists and one or two hypens and then a `while` loop with `index` can be faster. It was only stated in the comments (after I posted the original approach) that it's really about a large inputs.

Answer (score 4):

A bit weird but elegant way:

```
lst = ["I", "live", "in", "New", "-", "York", "City"]

pattern = "<erpvinpervin>"
s = pattern.join(lst)
s = s.replace("{0}-{0}".format(pattern), "-")
lst = s.split(pattern)
```

As `pattern` you can use any arbitrary string that's impossible to meet in your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, item in enumerate(lista):
    if item == '-':  # Checks if current item is your separator
        lista[index-1] = ''.join(lista[index-1:index+2])  # Joins the 3 indexes (new-york or whatever.)
        lista.remove(lista[index]) #  Removes the "garbage" that remained from the actual list
        lista.remove(lista[index])
```

There might be better ways of doing this but this one works fine and is pretty simple to understand.